# White line on screen - software issue

Tags: windows-7

My kids just played with my PC and now there's a white line and I can't get it back to normal.
It's a software issue because when I take a screenshot there's nothing wrong
[image: via screenshot]
but actually is this 
[image: via phone]
It's some kind of split screen but I don't know exactly.

I'm on windows 7 64bit and dual monitor. The first monitor is normal, but not with this second monitor.
Main display (2) Samsung VGA - the trouble screen
Second display (1) Chimei DVI- normal

**Update 1:**

- I try to swap between main display and second display, vice versa. Still don't work
- Sometimes the monitor is shakes up and down but only below the line. The upper line don't move

Comment: If you swap monitor ports does it stay on the same screen, or stay on the same port?

Comment: I can't swap the port because it's dvi and vga. But I change the main display from monitor 1 to monitor 2, vice versa. The line still on the monitor 2.
Monitor 1 : chimei
Monitor 2 : samsung (main display)

Comment: Chimei is on dvi and samsung is vga port.

Comment: I still think it's a hardware fault. Swapping the primary & secondary from Windows doesn't tell us anything really. The fact that it doesn't show on a screen snap tells me it's either the video card or the monitor... but not which of those.

Answer (score 3):

> **It's a software issue because when I take a screenshot there's nothing wrong**

On the contrary that means its a hardware issue. Screenshots are not made by reading the physical LCD, they are made by reading internal memory.

You probably need to re-seat the connectors or replace the screen.

Here's what Dell [say](https://blog.dell.com/en-us/lcd-lines-common-causes/)

> The most common cause of these lines is simply a loose connection. As notebook systems are carried around, no matter how careful we try to be, they have a tendency to be bumped, jarred, and even sometimes the heart stopping drop. Though  today's notebooks are designed to better absorb and dissipate small shocks, it can still have adverse affects on the notebook's internal components. A good bump or series of bumps and random movements can cause the LCD cable to become loose.

...

> If these simple fixes don't seem to work, then we need to look at the actual failure possibilities. Vertical or horizontal lines that don't disappear after the basic troubleshooting are usually caused by circumstantial failures. The most common type of failure that leads to lines on the display is an open circuit connection between the driver IC (flexible circuit board) and LCD glass. This is usually caused by external stresses (mechanical, thermal, etc…), which causes the flex circuit to detach from the glass.

Comment: oh Crap..I think you're right. I have reseat the port  but the line stills there.
Time to switch with better monitor I think.